# Python script suddenly gone from PC and dropbox...?

Tags: python, windows, dropbox

I realise this is a really vague "issue", but my Python scripts seem to have disappeared from my dropbox and PC suddenly.

Is there any known bug that could cause this? I really don't understand how this could've happend. Shortly before, I transferred some data files to the same folder.

I searched in my recycle bin: nothing there.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with Python. Has it selectively deleted Python scripts, or could it just have deleted a few directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with python, i guess your local folder and dropbox are synced and you simply overwrote the file.

Comment: FYI, it's not just that. I was wrong in saying dropbox, it was concerning OneDrive. It is a known issue, as you can see here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-files-disappeared/711b7951-a369-4812-98cd-a6af12c04066?page=1